# Get latest version of app from Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

How can I get the latest version of the app from the Appstore?

I want to compare current user version to the latest version on the Appstore.

If the version of the user is older than the one on the Appstore, I will notify him to update it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion) by nicklockwood.

It allows to automatically check for updates and inform the user about new features. It automatically detects when the new version of an app is released on the *App Store* and informs the user with a helpful alert that links them directly to the app download page.